# Adding text after a particular text in word

Tags: c#, .net, com, ms-word, activex

I am trying to access word application from C#.

I want to write a paragraph as soon as I find a particular text in a word file.

For example if I find a text/header "Address" in word doc, below this I would write complete address as contents.

I am trying to approach this by getting control of the cursor and placing it after I find address, but am unable to do. Can anyone please sugest an approach for the same.

Comment: What code do you have sofar?  Where do you get stuck or have problems?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to insert text into a document at a predetermined location.  If that's true then you should consider using Word's Bookmarks feature instead of searching for arbitrary text like "Address".  You can define bookmark names within a Word document (using the Insert > Bookmark command).  Bookmarks are easy to access from C#, allowing you to insert or replace text at that location.

For example, create a new Word document and enter some arbitrary text.  Select the text you want to be replaced, then click Insert > Bookmark and name the bookmark "BOOKMARK1".  Save and close the document.  You can now use code like the following to replace the text:

```
var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
var document = app.Documents.Open("c:\\temp\\interoptest.docx");
document.Bookmarks["BOOKMARK1"].Range.Text = "This text has been replaced.";
document.Save();
app.Quit(SaveChanges: false);
```

Note that you'll need to add a reference to the Microsoft Word Object Library for the above code to compile.  This library is found under the COM section when adding references in the most recent version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Hello,
Thanks a lot for your help.
Actually, I dont want to replace the bookmarked text, I am trying to insert a paragraph after a particular text, which can be present anywhere in the entire word doc. So, if I can get the range of the next line after the desired word, I can put my contents after that word.
Could you please help me with the same.

Comment: The Range property of the bookmark has a method called InsertAfter which will allow you to insert text.